# Degree of finite field extension by adjoining root of minimal polynomial

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Edited: Let $E$ be a finite degree extension field of $F_q$ where $q = p^n$, $p$ is some prime and $n$ is some integer, and $r \in E$. Let $g(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $r$ over the prime field $F_p$ of degree $d$. What is the number of elements of $F_p(r)$? The book I am reading claims it is $p^d$, but gives no justification to this and I am having trouble seeing this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is $q$ here?

Comment: If the minimal polynomial of $r$ over $F_p$ has degree $d$, then the degree of $F_p(r)$ over $F_p$ is $d$. $p^d$ is the number of elements of $F_p(r)$. So somebody is very confused.

Comment: @Batominovski, I added the details missing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you are absolutely right! I made a terrible mistake when asking the question, I was thinking of how to answer my question and wrote something else. The book claims $p^d$ is the number of elements of $F_p(r)$. Maybe I am missing something dumb, but I just can't see it.

Comment: So, any thoughts on my answer, 110320?

Comment: Sorry Gerry, I have been doing some other stuff for another class these past few days. I will return to this problem and your answer today in the afternoon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_p(r)=\{\,a_0+a_1r+\cdots+a_{d-1}r^{d-1}:a_i\in F_p\,\}$, and therefore the number of elements of $F_p(r)$ is $p^d$.

First, since $F_p(r)$ is a field containing $F_p$ and $r$, it must contain every polynomial in $r$ with coefficients in $F_p$, so it must contain all the elements I've listed. Second, the elements I've listed must all be distinct, since if any two were equal there would be a nonzero polynomial of degree at most $d-1$ vaninshing at $r$, contrary to the assumption that the minimal polynomial for $r$ has degree $d$. Third, no polynomial of higher degree is needed; since $r^d$ can be written as a polynomial in $r$ of degree less than $d$, so can any higher power of $r$, and thus any polynomial in $r$ of higher degree.

It remains to show that the set I've given is closed under taking multiplicative inverses. Certainly the set is a vector space over $F_p$ of degree $d$, so every $\beta$ in it satisfies an $F_p$-polynomial of degree at most $d$, and if $c_0+c_1\beta+\cdots+c_d\beta^d=0$, then $\beta\gamma=1$, where $\gamma=-c_0^{-1}(c_1+\cdots+c_d\beta^{d-1})$, which is in the set I've given. .

Comment: Thank you ! This is much clear now! Certainly the part I was missing was using/considering the degree of the minimal polynomial of r. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help. The recommended way to thank someone for a helpful answer is to "accept" the answer by clicking in the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I confused it with the upvote symbol